# In julia, how to extract a type T from instance DataStructures.Queue(T)?

Tags: julia

How can I extract a type from an instance of Queue?

## Array

For an array I can do this.

```
julia> a=UInt32[]

0-element Array{UInt32,1}

julia> eltype(a)

UInt32
```

## Deque

For a `Deque`, this workaround works.

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> d=Deque{UInt32}() 

Deque [UInt32[]]

julia> eltype(collect(d))

UInt32
```

## Queue ??

What should I do to extract type `UInt32` from a `Queue` `q`?

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> q=DataStructures.Queue(UInt32)

DataStructures.Queue{UInt32}(Deque [UInt32[]])
```

Comment: Another hack: `typeof(q).parameters[1]`

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why they don't have `eltype` -- the implementation seems rather trivial:

```
julia> q = Queue(Int)
DataStructures.Queue{Int64}(Deque [Int64[]])

julia> import Base: eltype

julia> Base.eltype{T}(::DataStructures.Queue{T}) = T

julia> eltype(q)
Int64
```

As it seems, in many types, the [optional methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-iteration) of the iterator interface are missing. Maybe they are too new.